# "Corrupt data" reported by exif

Tags: exif

I run `exif` on https://i.stack.imgur.com/teMe5.jpg

```
$ exif 4sftcoo.jpg 
Corrupt data
The data provided does not follow the specification.
ExifLoader: The data supplied does not seem to contain EXIF data.
```

I was wondering why the error?

Answer (score 2):

The answer you are looking for is **exiftool filename.jpg**

I just want to point out that FB removes or replaces most of the keys that identify YOU personally, they used to have a field that read "ban_account" (sometime last year?) as the value and it would put my account in timeout like 10 minutes after posting the photo

```
james@8300-SFF:~/Downloads$ exiftool 120450723_631453814209931_1925887118753716863_n.jpg
ExifTool Version Number         : 10.33
File Name                       : 120450723_631453814209931_1925887118753716863_n.jpg
Directory                       : .
File Size                       : 28 kB
File Modification Date/Time     : 2020:10:01 16:59:26-04:00
File Access Date/Time           : 2020:10:01 17:00:10-04:00
File Inode Change Date/Time     : 2020:10:01 16:59:28-04:00
File Permissions                : rw-rw-r--
File Type                       : JPEG
File Type Extension             : jpg
MIME Type                       : image/jpeg
JFIF Version                    : 1.02
Resolution Unit                 : None
X Resolution                    : 1
Y Resolution                    : 1
Current IPTC Digest             : 7549a31ec9fd5e72122115c64d3e8be9
Special Instructions            : FBMD01000aa2010000660d0000261e00002a220000ec2600007f360000f6490000f24c00006a510000d7550000ea6f0000
Original Transmission Reference : dHVOFM1DHmPLnMW15mYi
Image Width                     : 540
Image Height                    : 434
Encoding Process                : Progressive DCT, Huffman coding
Bits Per Sample                 : 8
Color Components                : 3
Y Cb Cr Sub Sampling            : YCbCr4:2:0 (2 2)
Image Size                      : 540x434
Megapixels                      : 0.234
james@8300-SFF:~/Downloads$ exiftool 120450723_631453814209931_1925887118753716863_n.jpg
```

Comment: No, in my Ubuntu, the correct command is "exif file.jpg"

Answer (score 0):

May be the data has been removed from the given image.
In general facebook and other social medias removes such data